# User authentication issue

Tags: .net

I need to develop module which will authenticate a company user on local systems. My company vendors using card + VPN connect to our network. I found that LSA Authentication is exactly what I need, but it so complex what I am having difficulty to understand what is going on.

Could any one describe flow and methods which I need to use to get a desired results. So all I need is to get authenticated user domain and username. Or maybe someone could suggest another option.

Thanks!